# Why is my Segmented control not reacting?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working with an iPhone application in Xcode and I want to use a segmented control with 4 different choices.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong and why the NSLog messages don't show when I click on it?

This is my code:

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Format : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *papper;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *papper;

-(IBAction)papperskontrollSwitched:(id)sender;
```

.m file:

```
#import "Format.h"

@implementation Format

@synthesize papper;

-(IBAction)papperskontrollSwitched:(id)sender{
    if(papper.selectedSegmentIndex==0){

        NSLog(@"A5 valdes");
    } 

    else if(papper.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

        NSLog(@"A4 valdes");
    }

    else if(papper.selectedSegmentIndex==2){

        NSLog(@"A3 valdes");
    }

    else if(papper.selectedSegmentIndex==3){

        NSLog(@"Visitkort valdes");
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Please check you have linked the UISegmentedControl in IB to both the property and the action (control drag a line).

Comment: Ive checked and they are both linked.

Comment: Why are you defining an instance variable AND a property for this segmented control? This is probably causing things to not react appropriately.

Comment: Did you connect your method to Value Changed? You might wrongly connect it to Touch Up Inside.

Comment: Does the IBAction method have a filled gray dot on its left side?

Comment: Oh now it does work! I had chose touch up inside and changed to value changed and it works :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the stuff in the brackets:

```
{
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *papper;
}
```

There's no need for it when you have this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *papper;
```

Comment: tried the code by @Cornelia G and it worked fine for me.. any comment

Comment: Yes the IBAction is connected and have a grey dot on the side. Ive also deleted the IBOutlets in the interface brackets but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @Cornelia G you might have missed "value changed" action just delete the action and again link it.

Comment: Yes that was the problem now it works, thanks for your help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Having an ivar and a `@property` shouldn't matter here and indeed when I'm using this exact code in a test project it is working perfectly.

Ensure your `UISegmentedControl` is connected to the `papper` outlet in Interface Builder and you've connected the `UISegmentedControl`'s 'Value Changed' action to `-(IBAction)papperskontrollSwitched:`

[image]